# How to programmatically read schema from header file in jaql?

Tags: biginsights, jjaql

I am trying to achieve the following in JAQL and am stuck.

I have two files: File data.tsv, which contains tab separated data, and a file header.tsv, which contains exactly one line with tab separated values, corresponding to the "header" of file data.tsv.

What I want to achieve is to read data.tsv using:

```
read(lines(location='data.tsv')) -> transform catch(delToJson($, {"schema": schema_json, "delimiter": "\t"}), {"errThresh":99999999999},$);
```

For this I need schema_json, a schema definition. I'd like to create this schema_json from file header.tsv (and assigning every field the type "string").

Reading header.tsv is straight forward, and putting it into a *record* of type `header_record = {"header1": string, "header2":string, ....}` as well. However how do I transform the jaql *record* header_record to an object of type *schema:* `schema_json = schema {"header1":string,"header2":string, ....}`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a very dirty workaround, that nevertheless does the trick. I am still waiting for IBM support to get back to me with "the canonical way" (although I doubt this exists):

First, define path of the header file

```
HeaderFilePath = '/data/column_headers.tsv';
```

Then read the header file. Output is an array.

```
HeaderFile = localRead(del(location=HeaderFilePath, delimiter = "\t"));
```

Now I construct two arrays of the same length as the HeaderFile array, in order to use them with `arrayToRecord` in the next step. Why I construct two and not just one will be apparent later.

```
val_array = HeaderFile -> expand -> transform 'some string';
val_array2 = HeaderFile -> expand -> transform 'some other string';
```

The idea is to build an artificial record schema_record with the same schema as the data and then to get the schema via `schemaof`, which then can be used as schema input for reading the data file.
For this one can use

```
schema_record = arrayToRecord(HeaderFile -> expand,val_array)
```

Problems:

a) `schemaof(schema_record)` returns `schema { * }?`. This is because schemas can (seemingly) only be inferred from materialized data, i.e. one has to use `schema_record := arrayToRecord(HeaderFile -> expand,val_array)`.

b) Now, using `schemaof(schema_record)` returns a schema. Which is good. However, I don't understand why a schema function would do something like this, but the schema record looks something like `"header1": @{const: "some string", fixed: 11} string` instead of the expected `"header1": string`. Hence this "schema" is pretty much useless. What is worse, there seems to be no way to manipulate that schema object, such that one might be able to remove the `@{}` specifications.

Workaround: use function `elementsOf`, which returns the schema of elements of an array of schemas. Meaning:

```
elementsOf([schemaof({a:1,b:3}),{a:1,b:3}]); 
>> schema {"a":@{const: 1, fixed: 1} long, "b":@{const: 3, fixed: 1} long}.
```

However, using schemas with different "const" and "fixed" records will force `elementsOf` to fall back to a "raw" schema (without @{})

```
elementsOf([schemaof({a:1,b:3}),{a:45,b:32}])
>> schema {"a": long, "b": long}.
```

This is the "dirty workaround" that I use to achieve what I want. (And all this is due to a very strange understanding of what a schema is...)

```
schema_array := [arrayToRecord(HeaderFile -> expand, val_array),arrayToRecord(HeaderFile -> expand, val_array2)];

DataSchema := elementsOf(schemaof(schema_array));

Data = read(lines(location='/data/data.tsv')) -> transform catch(delToJson($,
{"schema": DataSchema, "delimiter": "\t"}), {"errThresh": 99999999999},$);
```